# jquery append not working after using replace in textarea

Tags: jquery, replace, append, textarea, toggle

I've got some checkbox list item text that needs to be added and removed from a textarea as a user selects and deselects the list item checkboxes.

It works the first time through, that is selecting a checkbox adds the list item text to the textarea, for all of the list items, and then deselecting the checkboxes successfully removes the respective list item text from the textarea.

But when any checkbox is clicked again after having deselected it, the text is not re-appended to the textarea, when I need it to work for infinity selects and deselects of list items.

I think it has to do with how I am using a replace to remove the string for a respective list item.  Somehow that prevents the append from working a second/third/etc time.  Or, maybe it has to do with val() and append() not playing nice together.  I've done a bunch of searching for an answer, and trial and error with my scripting, but am just getting confused at this point.

In short, I successfully toggle a class for these list items upon user clicks, and I basically need to likewise toggle the text from each list item to a nearby textarea.  The text "toggle" currently only works one time, though, on and off, but not on again.

**Here's my simple HTML code:**

```
    <div class="textwrapper">

                    <p>Check off the questions you will be answering.</p>

                    <ul>
                        <li title="select question">What was your biggest takeaway from this?</li>

                        <li title="select question">What part of this struck you the most?</li>

                        <li title="select question">What part do you want to know more about?</li>
                    </ul>

                </div>

                <div id="topic-form">
                    <textarea></textarea>
                </div>
```

Not seen in that code is the CSS that makes a checkbox-looking background image swap from unselected to selected states as a "selected" class is added or removed accordingly to each list item.  That bit works fine.

**And here's my JS:**

```
    $('.textwrapper li').click(function() {

        questionText = $(this).text() + '\n\n';

        currTextareaText = $('#topic-form textarea').val();

        if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
            newTextareaText = currTextareaText.replace(questionText, '');
            $('#topic-form textarea').val(newTextareaText);
        } else {
                //$('#topic-form textarea').val(questionText);
                $('#topic-form textarea').append(questionText);
            }
        }

        questionTitle = $(this).attr('title');
        if (questionTitle == 'select question'){
            $(this).attr({'title':'deselect question'});    
        } else {
            $(this).attr({'title':'select question'});
        }

        $(this).toggleClass('selected');

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your `$('#topic-form textarea').append(questionText);` to `$('#topic-form textarea').val($('#topic-form textarea').val() + questionText);` and it will be working.

```
 $('.textwrapper li').click(function() {
     questionText = $(this).text() + '\n\n';
     currTextareaText = $('#topic-form textarea').val();

     if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
         newTextareaText = currTextareaText.replace(questionText, '');
     } else {
         newTextareaText = currTextareaText + questionText;
     }
      $('#topic-form textarea').val(newTextareaText);

     questionTitle = $(this).attr('title');
     if (questionTitle == 'select question'){
         $(this).attr({'title':'deselect question'});    
     } else {
         $(this).attr({'title':'select question'});
     }

     $(this).toggleClass('selected');
 });
```

See jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/nrobert/jsB5n/3/

Comment: And seems though you already have the val() in a variable it could just be `$('#topic-form textarea').val(currTextareaText + questionText);`

Comment: Beautiful, and so fast.  Thanks a ton.  I've already tested independently and that's just what I needed.  I feel a bit of relief in that I was in the ballpark at least.  Note that I got rid of the "if (currTextareaText == '')" because that was just thinking it might have had something to do with textarea value being empty, and getting confused with the val() and append(). Again, thank you.  (I'd upvote if I could as a new user.)

Comment: Even cleaner: setting only your newTextareaText val and 1 line of update of your textarea (see edit). You will upvote later with more reputation ;) but you are able to accept right now, no?

Comment: The latest is very elegant and lean.  I like it.  Thank you so much!  (I think I just accepted with the green checkmark - new to this)